# Angular 2 - Reload current route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have navigation header in my app that contains two links:

```
<a [routerLink]="/home"></a>
<a [routerLink]="/about"></a>
```

By default I am on the /home screen.  I'd like the /home screen to be reloaded when I click on it.

Also, I have listeners set up to watch the router state change:

```
this._router.events.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
```

However, this is not triggering.

Is this do-able with Angular 2?  Angular 1 provides $route.reload(), but I don't see the equivalent anywhere in the Docs or in my Google Searches.

NOTE: I'm not looking to use window.reload() to reload the entire app.  I only want the current page to be reloaded.

Comment: why do you really need to reload home screen?

Comment: @MaximKuzmin Within the home screen there's a card and within that card there are two different views A and B.  View A has a button that when clicked, will hide A and show B via *ngIf.  In this scenario, when I click on the /home link, I'd like to restore the page to its default state so that View A shows by reloading the route.

Comment: you should bind home with B view to nested route then (home/b). It will solve your issue

Comment: @MaximKuzmin ok thanks this is what I thought about as well.

Comment: should I post detailed answer?

Comment: This can now be done in Angular 5.1 using the onSameUrlNavigation property of the Router config. Explaining how here : https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2